# Would it be useful for a tag to specify reasons why a question might get closed for community reasons?

Tags: discussion

JSON Schema is a specification which people use to validate and annotate JSON data.
We have a sizable community we often support via Stack Overflow, and we pipe a feed of tagged questions into our slack server. I'm the JSON Schema core team lead, which means I often end up doing a fair amount of admin and community support work.

I've seen a number of questions over the year where someone asks something along the lines of "Why doesn't THING work?" and the answer is often "You forgot to nest under `properties`".

For those of you who don't know JSON Schema, this is the equivalent of "You didn't call the right function" or "You misspelled your function. The function is actually fine".

I have on occasion voted to close these types of issues, specifying the reason as a community reason, following up with a comment to explain.

Is it appropriate / useful for a tag page to identify potential community related reasons for closing questions, such as described above?

Here's an example of such a question: [minLength not working in json schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629500/minlength-not-working-in-json-schema-validation)

Comment: This seems to match the "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" close reason, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not quite. I mean more like "Please check for correct use of applicators. If you're unsure what this means, please check the guide at URL." to try and avoid questions which will not help anyone else; the JSON Schema equivalent of a typo.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, this is what I mean. I AM using that reason to vote to close. I'm asking should I list "typo" like reasons on the tag's page?

Comment: I think I'd phrase it more as a check-list of common reasons why a schema might not work and encourage askers to check for those before posting, but you might find that a lot of people won't read the tag wiki in the first place.

Comment: Hey look, you've got some free UX feedback! In version 2, make it so you don't need to nest under `properties`.

Comment: Ha. No. That would make several things impossible. And we're at "version 8" now, which is going to be part of OpenAPI 3.1 once released. We been busy.

Answer (score 38):

Why not create a canonical question and answer for this, similar to Java's [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

That way you can duplicate questions to the canonical.

If you explain in the canonical's answer how to deal with the issue then you'll help everyone we point in that direction.

Comment: Yeah although I'm not sure how I would phrase the question. It's "X does not work in JSON Schema` where X is any of the keywords (20 something). The user (Schema author) won't get an error message... it will just appear that the keyword they are trying to use, does nothing.

Comment: "<keyword> does not work in JSON Schema" perhaps, then list the keywords in the question or its answer.

Comment: If that's going to be considered OK and not too vague, then yeah, I'll go with that. Thanks!

Comment: And it might be nice to link to this from the tag explanation -- who knows, someone applying the tag might notice that their question is already answered!

Comment: @Relequestual I think it will be OK, especially since you are basing it off of a Meta discussion. Worst cast, gather together fellow [tag:json] users (preferably gold badge holders) to help support you in some initial canonical-writing and duplicate-closing efforts. If it takes ages to get momentum as a canonical dupe, the chances increase of the broader site community having an issue with it/not realizing its intent.

Comment: We (JSON Schema) has a tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema I'll add this to my todo!

Comment: @Relequestual Canonical questions often are worded vaguely indeed, and might even fall under the "too broad" close condition normally. Putting a comment or disclaimer on them stating that it's a canonical might be a good idea, if the fact that they are often self-answered questions by a high-reputation user isn't enough of a hint. They also need a very good and on-topic answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Bergi - I'm hoping given I'm the JSON Schema core team lead, my answer to my own question will be very on-topic and of very high quality.

Comment: @Relequestual I would assume so :-) For the question itself, don't just state the problem in a clear way, but possibly also add some "related" questions (even if it reads like it's repeating the same thing over and over) so that the question will be found with any possible search terms.

Answer (score 5):

That is not the right approach. We have been [discouraging meta-tags for over 10 years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

> Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the *only*
> tag on a question

As Robert said, you should be making a canonical duplicate target for this.

It completely depends on the overlap between the problems people are asking related to keywords -- I'll defer to you as the expert on that -- but there's nothing to say you have to squeeze everything into one question. You can make as many canonical questions as make sense. Whether there are some logical groupings that exist, or whether you make 1 question per keyword, I'll leave that up to you.

Better yet, rather than creating a load of questions from scratch, if you're seeing these questions all the time then you should be able to find the best/most general one, edit it to improve it, and make that the canonical question for all future close votes. You have plenty of answers already, I'm sure you can salvage something from them.

Once the canonical question/questions exist, you will need to be consistent about closing duplicate questions to point to them, so that other users active in the tag will know that they exist and will start to do the same.

It would help a lot if you or someone in your community had a gold badge. It would allow you to single-handedly close a question that you know is a duplicate. If I were you, I'd be looking for a way to get enough rep to be able to do this. Maybe if the [jsonschema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema) tag's not active enough, you could try to get a gold badge in a tag which is commonly used in combination with it, like [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json).

If you can't get a gold badge or until you get one, you should become active in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/). This is a chatroom where you can request other users vote to close a question. In addition to your personal vote, you would only need 2 additional close votes from people in the chat.

You could also see whether 2 or more people involved with JSON Schema community would be happy to participate in moderating the tag with you casting close votes. It doesn't seem like a hugely active tag, so it would only take a few minutes a day.

---

Some things to be aware of, based on my experience dupe-hammering in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag:

People are disappointingly lazy. If you link to a huge question which addresses multiple issues, or multiple causes of the same problem, you will get people complaining "*that doesn't answer my question*", and most of the time they won't have even read it thoroughly.

People also hate having their questions closed. A lot of the time, the reason why they didn't just Google the answer in the first place is that they want someone to spoon-feed them a solution that's precisely tailored for them. Do not tolerate it. As far as I'm concerned, you're the expert on which questions are a duplicate and which are not. If someone doesn't want to read a dupe target after you've taken the time to point them in that direction then that's their problem, not yours.

Answer (score 3):

We get a similar issue in XSLT-land, where the most common user error (by far) is to use an unprefixed name in the stylesheet to match a source document that has a default namespace. This has been recognised as an unfortunate feature of the language spec for many years, but it can't be changed for compatibility reasons. Although there are at least 700 questions where this turns out to be the answer, they still arrive at about one per day, and because the questions are all different (it's only the answer that's the same) people have been reluctant to close them as duplicates. I've taken to closing them as duplicates, but I hate doing it because of the implication that the user should have found the answer before asking the question, when in fact the only way they could find the answer would be if they already knew it. (OK, it would be nice if people read up on a language before they started coding, but hey, this is 2020.) So, no easy solution, but I think that closing it as a duplicate -- as nicely as possible -- is the best approach.

Comment: Wait, the problem doesn't have a common characteristic other than the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it appropriate / useful for a tag page to identify potential community related reasons for closing questions, such as described above?

No.

The users are barely reading tags wiki to see if tag is *fully* appropriate or even *barely* fits. They will not read *longer* tags wiki to see if their future question *may* get closed. Neither they read after it *was* closed.

Every year new *beginners* born to repeat your or mine path. Popular questions will be asked again and again. E.g. "how to pass value from X to Y" between classes, forms, etc.  require basic OOP knowledge and experience and until those will come with mother milk expect questions.

I am personally waiting for Skynet - the AI good enough to either answer questions or eradicate all stupid humans. Until then find the best duplicate, add it to favorites and use every time you see *another* such question.

Comment: Your first argument fully matches my first thought when reading the question. But I hereby distance myself from your wish of some powerful AI taking over stackoverflow.